# How to edit the embedded PDF in a html page

Tags: javascript, html, pdf

I am working on a E signing application.the app has lot of pdf documents for the user to read and sign it.In the PDF document there are some places where the user has to enter the name, date and a unique number to sign the document.I can embed the document into the page using the following line

```
<embed src="sample.pdf" width="800px" height="2100px" />
```

but i don't know how to edit the pdf document.guys pls help me out how i can embed and edit the documents for the signing the pdf

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: you can't edit pdf . but you can generate it from existing docs/html form

Comment: Hi @user can you pls tell me how to convert it to html form

Comment: @codegeek that's far too broad for an SO question and you can research it yourself https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=Javascript+PDF+to+HTML&oq=Javascript+PDF+to+HTML&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.2668j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: do you want to convert pdf to html? so need to parsde pdf and design form from that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will ***never*** be able to get any kind of consistency in the end user experience if you use the embed tag to display your PDF. The embed tag tells the browser to use either it's built-in PDF viewer or the default PDF viewer for that operating system. Most PDF viewers can't handle PDF signatures at all... and the viewres that do, no longer can display their PDF in modern browsers. My recommendation is to use something like Adobe Sign or DocuSign. Both will allow you to use PDF as the input and get PDF as the output, but uses an HTML redition of the PDF and an HTML5-based UI for the signing process.